# ArcGIS Pro Troubleshooting Feature Dataset- some layers not drawing

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class, feature-dataset

I have an enterprise geodatabase with multiple feature datasets. I have one feature dataset that will not load any of the feature classes. One work around is to copy/paste the needed layer multiple times into the map until the feature shows. However, sometimes I only get a partial drawing. The more times I copy/paste, the more of the feature that draws. Is there an issue with my feature dataset?

Comment: I usually try to start with the assumption that Pro is just not working correctly (since I run into issues all the time). Have you attempted to clear the geoprocessing cache?

Comment: Keep in mind that at feature dataset is only a metadata property in the GDB catalog. I would suggest making a complete, verifiable backup of the RDBMS, moving the feature classes out of the dataset, deleting the dataset, recreating the dataset, and moving the feature classes back in, and then resetting the permissions on the FDS.